# Fedora 29 graphical login screen (sddm) displays only virtual keyboard

Tags: fedora, login-manager, sddm

I've upgraded from Fedora 27 to 29. The upgrade itself passed fine, just after final reboot, the graphical login screen (sddm) just flickered standard screen with users and then displays virtual keyboard on black background. Similar to this picture:

[image]

What can I do to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtual keyboard should be by default diplayed on devices without HW keyboard (like tablets). However not on normal PC with keyboard attached.

To avoid virtual keyboard in the sddm open `/etc/sddm.conf`, find the section `[General]` and put there `InputMethod=` without any value. Like this:

```
[General]
InputMethod=
```

As of now the virtual keyboard should not be displayed by default.